# Moving background doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm trying to make my background move endlessly from left to right repeatedly. I tried all sorts of things, but I don't know why the code doesn't work.

Here's my code

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />

      <script src="JS/javascript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>

    </main>
    <div id="section1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var i=null;

window.onload = function(){
    var move = setInterval(move, 30);
    move();
}

function move(){
    i++;
    document.getElementById("section1").style.backgroundPosition=i+"px";
}
```

Comment: CSS:#section1{
    width:1600px;
    height: 900px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url("../IMG/Background.png");
    background-size: cover;
} (This site wouldn't let me post this code :/)

Comment: try make var "i" not null but int 0 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are updated code for your requirement.

You only need pass move method to `setInterval`, don't need call move() after `setInterval`

```js
var i=1;
function move(){
    i++;
    document.getElementById("section1").style.backgroundPosition=i+"px";
}
window.onload = function(){
    var move1 = setInterval(move, 30);
    //move();
}
```

```css
#section1{
height: 200px;
background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/08/21/11/wood-1963988__340.jpg')
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />

      <script src="JS/javascript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>

    </main>
    <div id="section1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) to achieve this.

```css
#section1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1000?text=test image');
  background-size:cover;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: scroll;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="section1"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't thought about doing it that way. Thanks for sharing :)!

Comment: Exactly, I was just preparing something like this